# problem when exporting and importing in fbx

Tags: mesh, export, import, .fbx

I have a problem when exporting or importing FBX files to blender, I don't know how to solve it and I don't know why so I prepared a photo to be evaluated, the problem is that when importing models in fbx format it seems that it has parts of invisible mesh, I searched the internet and found nothing like this so I had no choice but to request help here.

[image]

[image]

I use as an example this model that I download
but the problem is with any model I make

Comment: This looks like backface culling, go to your material settings > Settings and check if Backface Culling is enabled or not, if it is, turn it off, Also it may be due to multiple materials, so check all your materials

Comment: hey that fixed the little problem! Thank you so much! you're my hero

Comment: don't forget that whenever you see back of your mesh from front it may be this